# Non-PIE Binary - The executable 'project name' is not a Position Independent Executable.

Tags: iphone, pie-chart

I uploaded a binary on into iTunes Connect, it was validated and accepted to publish to the App Store. I received an email from Apple, saying that my application is an invalid binary:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "Project name". To process your delivery, the following issues must be
>   corrected:
>
> **iPhone 5 Optimization Requirement** - Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5. As of May 1, all new iPhone apps and app updates
>   submitted must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5. All apps must
>   include a launch image of the appropriate size. Learn more about
>   iPhone 5 support by reviewing the iOS Human Interface Guidelines.
>
> Though you are not required to fix the following issues, we wanted to
>   make you aware of them:
>
> **Non-PIE Binary** - The executable 'xyz.app' is not a Position Independent Executable. Please ensure that your build settings are
>   configured to create PIE executables. Once the required corrections
>   have been made, go to the Version Details page and click "Ready to
>   Upload Binary." Continue through the submission process until the app
>   status is "Waiting for Upload." You can then deliver the corrected
>   binary.

I have changed the `Don't Create Position Independent Executables` option in `Target` > `Build Settings` to `YES`, but I still receive the same message above.

Answer (score 8):

There is now a document from Apple explaining the issue and how to solve it: [QA1788: Building a Position Independent Executable](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1788/),

> ### Steps for building your application as PIE
>
> 1. In Xcode, select your target in the "Targets" section, then click the "Build Settings" tab to view its settings.
> 2. For iOS apps, set `iOS Deployment Target` to **iOS 4.3 or later**. For Mac apps, set `OS X Deployment Target` to **OS X 10.7 or later**.
> 3. Verify that `Generate Position-Dependent Code` is set at to **NO**.
> 4. Verify that `Don't Create Position Independent Executables` is set to **NO**.

Comment: Thanks for this help. I have read above given link and apply in my xcode and i test my build in my otool -hv in folder "/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/dkpad.app/dkpad". but as according the link header flag does not show "PIE". Header flag is show like "NOUNDEFS DYLDLINK TWOLEVEL MH_NO_HEAP_EXECUTION". my mac osx version 10.6.8(snow leopad),xcode version 4.0 and ios version 4.3. Please give passible cause for this. Thank you.

Comment: If otool is showing that your app isn't PIE, then it's possible that a particular target is overriding a build setting. Triple check your build settings. Also hold down Option and choose "Clean Build Folder" from the "Product" menu, possibly Xcode didn't rebuild the app.

Comment: @VincentGable How do you achieve PIE-executable when these settigns are explicitly set to no? They seem to force it now, build settings are SET yet I get the error.

Comment: @AntwanvanHoudt Are you able to solve this? I just receive this warning now

Comment: @JaysonTamayo Apple seems to have removed the constrictions on ITC, but I wouldn't be surprised we will have to update Xcode to fix this in the future.

Comment: Why is the option called `Don't Create Position Independent Executables`? Double negatives are confusing.

Answer (score 5):

We're getting the same message on all of our app updates this week.
You will need to set "Don't Create Position Independent Executables" to "NO" and "Generate Position-Dependent Code" to "NO", which is the default.

The key is that you will need to set "iOS Deployment Target" to 4.3 or later, or the PIE settings will be ignored.

You can test the app binary with this command and it will show "PIE" at the end of the line for a PIE exe.
otool -vh MyAppExe

Comment: Thanks for response. have u successfully publish your iphone app on itune or not . please explain last line of your response . can you tell me if i set "iOS Deployment Target" to 4.3 or later, than it will be applicable to lower version of ios .

Comment: If you change the "iOS Deployment Target" to 4.3 then your app will no longer be compatible with older iOS versions and this will be displayed in iTunes.
We have not made the PIE change as we still want to support the older iOS versions, but remember that the Apple feedback is just a reminder and you don't have to make this change ....yet.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned here by Vincent, to have a PIE-Binary:

- follow [Apple Q&A QA1788](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1788/_index.html)
- set deployment target to 4.3 as minimum OS version (this is a requirement for PIE-Binary)
- **(the missing bit)**: make sure you don't have a 3rd party library that would not be compatible with PIE-binary, otherwise the all project will not build for PIE-Binary.
- check with: `otool -hv /path/to/MyApp.app/MyApp`

This said, Apple does not force you "YET" to have a PIE-Binary app. So the question is "will they force to do so ? and when ?"

_oho

more info: http://blog.hoachuck.biz/blog/2013/06/28/non-pie-binary-app-on-ios-could-lead-to-security-issue/

Comment: and how would you check whether a 3rd-party library is compatible with PIE?