# titanium submitting app - missing a required architecture,iphone5,Invalid Launch Image, non-pie binary

Tags: architecture, submit, titanium, launch

I just cant get Titanium app to submit to AppStore.

Here is what Im using:
3.1.0 GA
xcode 4.6

Firstly, this is what I got when uploading:
1.
"iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable is missing a required architecture. At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv6

I tried to fix this problem with this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1760/_index.html
but it didnt work. So, one of the post suggest to use xcode 4.3

now uploading works, but i get this bunch of problems.
How can I solve them ?? if Im using xcode 4.3, i cant get iOS 6.0. 
Its like a chicken an egg problem. Whats worst this iphone5 came into effect May 1, means its recent. So what can Appcelerator do to help me with this ?

**iPhone 5 Optimization Requirement** - Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5. As of May 1, all new iPhone apps and app updates submitted must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5. All apps must include a launch image with the -568h size modifier immediately following the  portion of the launch image's filename. Launch images must be PNG files and located at the top-level of your bundle, or provided within each .lproj folder if you localize your launch images. Learn more about iPhone 5 support and app launch images by reviewing the iOS Human Interface Guidelines and iOS App Programming Guide.

**Invalid Launch Image** - Your app contains a launch image with a size modifier that is only supported for apps built with the iOS 6.0 SDK or later.

Though you are not required to fix the following issues, we wanted to make you aware of them:

**Non-PIE Binary** - The executable 'test.app' is not a Position Independent Executable. Please ensure that your build settings are configured to create PIE executables.

Thanks a whole lot... there is nothing special with my app... im using all the latest versiosns

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue here....
To resolve **Invalid Launch Image** I think you have to check **Resource/iphone** folder, this folder must contain only valid splash images name for the iOS sdk you are using.
In my case: **appicon.png**, **Default.png**, **Default@2x.png**, **Default-Landscape.png** and **Default-Portrait.png**

Hope this help...

Comment: more info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455416/non-pie-binary-the-executable-project-name-is-not-a-position-independent-exe