# Non-PIE binary built regardless of build settings

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm receiving the following message from Apple when submitting an iOS app to the App Store:

> Non-PIE Binary - The executable 'Celly.app' is not a Position
>   Independent Executable. Please ensure that your build settings are
>   configured to create PIE executables. For more information, refer to
>   [Technical Q&A QA1788 - Building a Position Independent Executable](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1788/_index.html#/apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013354)

The info at the link says I should do the following:

> In Xcode, select your target in the "Targets" section, then click the
>   "Build Settings" tab to view its settings. For iOS apps, set iOS
>   Deployment Target to iOS 4.3 or later. For Mac apps, set OS X
>   Deployment Target to OS X 10.7 or later. Verify that Generate
>   Position-Dependent Code is set at its default value of NO. Verify that
>   Don't Create Position Independent Executables is set at its default
>   value of NO.

I've followed the directions at the link they provided, making sure that the build settings regarding generating Position-Independent Binaries are set to 'NO,' and have also verified that my project's iOS deployment target is iOS 5.1.

I don't think it should affect the final product, but I'm using Mogenerator to create my Core Data managed objects. I've verified that the Mogenerator target also has the correct settings.

I'm also using a variety of libraries through Cocoapods, and have verified that the settings on each of them are correct as well, and that they all have deployment targets of iOS 5.1.

However, even with these settings, my app is still non-PIE. I can only assume that there is something hidden within the project somewhere that is overriding my build settings and causing the app to be built as position-dependent. I'm really quite unfamiliar with the concept of PIE, so any information about what could be causing this would be appreciated. Are there any other places I should be checking that could affect whether or not my app is PIE? Are there things that I might be doing in my code that could potentially cause my app to build non-PIE?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455416/non-pie-binary-the-executable-project-name-is-not-a-position-independent-exe the libraries you use must also be PIE.

Comment: @JaakL I've gone through and checked that all the libraries I'm using have the proper PIE settings. However, I'm not sure if they are actually generating PIEs, since they may be suffering from the same issues that my containing project is. Is there a way to verify for each library, independently, if they are generating PIEs? If I had a process for that, I could be able to pinpoint the origin of my problem.

Comment: I got this for a project right now. The project is built by a 3rd party dev and they used Unity3d. "armv7/Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll.o." comes up as having PIE disabled. It's something with Unity/C#... or dog knows :-P

Comment: @Jonny: How do you check whether a library has PIE enabled or not?

Comment: Sorry I don't remember any of this :-D

Answer (score 0):

You can check each binary or library by using otool.

Go to location of framework or app. e.x. /[DerivedData dir]/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos

otool -hv LibraryName.framework/LibraryName

or

otool -hv AppName.app/AppName

Look for "PIE" in the flags section. Here is sample output:

`AppName.app/AppName (architecture armv7):
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
   MH_MAGIC     ARM         V7  0x00     EXECUTE    45       4600   NOUNDEFS DYLDLINK TWOLEVEL WEAK_DEFINES BINDS_TO_WEAK PIE`

`AppName.app/AppName (architecture arm64):
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
MH_MAGIC_64   ARM64        ALL  0x00     EXECUTE    45       5184   NOUNDEFS DYLDLINK TWOLEVEL WEAK_DEFINES BINDS_TO_WEAK PIE`